# Failing to write data to firestore using flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write some data into firestore, more exactly, a collection containing a document that has a few fields but for some reason it fails.

```dart
 void createChatRoom() async {
    instructorUID = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;
    chatRoomID = clientUID + instructorUID;

    if(db.collection('chatrooms').document(chatRoomID) == null) {
      db.collection('chatrooms').document(chatRoomID).setData({
        'instructor': instructorUID,
        'instructorName': widget.name,
        'client': clientUID,
        'clientPhoneNo': clientPhoneNo,
        'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      });
    }

    Navigator.push(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ChatPage(
          chatRoomID: chatRoomID,
          clientUID: clientUID,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Maybe I am not assigning the chatRoomId well?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work, I had to rewrite the if statement as Richard suggested and make a method for saving data in order to use aynchronous programming as intended :

```dart
void saveData() async {
    await db.collection('instructori').document(instructorUID).collection('chatrooms').document(chatRoomID).setData({
        'instructor': instructorUID,
        'instructorName': widget.name,
        'clientPhoneNo': clientPhoneNo,
        'client': clientUID,
        'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
  }

void createChatRoom() async {
   instructorUID = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;
   chatRoomID = "test";

   if(await db.collection('instructori').document(instructorUID).collection('chatrooms').document(chatRoomID).get() == null)
   {
      print(instructorUID);
      saveData();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the condition in your "if" statement will always be false, since it's comparing a DocumentReference object to null. Instead you should call "get" on the DocumentReference first (using "await"), then compare that result to null. If it's null then you should call "setData".

For example:

```
if(await db.collection('chatrooms').document(chatRoomID).get() == null)
```

Also I believe "await" should be used to wait on the "setData" call.

Comment: I tried to implement this but I get the following error: The method 'getData' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getData'.

Comment: Sorry, it should be "get". I just edited my answer.

Comment: Well, I get no errors but the collection still isn't saved to firestore...

Comment: I am a bit confused, when I write the data I should use setData, not set(), am I right?

Comment: You're right. I'm the confused one, haha. I was mixing it up with the Firestore JavaScript library.

Comment: Just for testing, can you set chatRoomID to a simple string like "test" to rule out whether it's an issue with the ID?

Comment: I also removed the if statement but still doesn't work

Comment: Any luck if you add "await" to your "setData" call?

Comment: No luck unfortunatelly

Comment: Is this the only call to setData in your app so far

Comment: No, I also call it when the user registers

Comment: Also, do you have Firestore security rules configured?

Comment: It works well, I do have the security rules on public

Comment: Can you add your working code which creates a Firestore document when user registers?

Comment: Ok, it finally worked, but the if statement doesn't really work well

Comment: Check out the answer